# VBA - extract multiple decimal numbers from a string

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry still new to VBA and was hoping to get help from the community.
I am trying to pull all decimal numbers from a string.  I was able to find this code below, but it only pulls the first decimal number and I was wondering how I can change it so that it pulls all decimal numbers?
Example is for string "60.75X30.75 Oak" to pull both 60.75 and 30.75 but the code below only pulls 60.75.

```
Function realNum(str As String, _
                  Optional ndx As Integer = 1)
    Dim tmp As String
    Static rgx As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If
    realNum = 0

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,9}\.[0-9]{1,9}"
        If .Test(str) Then
            realNum = CDbl(.Execute(str)(ndx - 1))
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: If your strings are of the same format then Split(Split(str," ")(0),"X") will return an array of "60.75","30.75".

Comment: Are the decimals optional? What about thousands, say 1,234.56? Can there be more than two numbers in a string? How do you wish to use these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

```
Function realNum(str As String, _
                  Optional ndx As Integer = 1)
    Dim tmp As String
    Static rgx As Object

    'with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If
    'realNum = 0    edited

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,9}\.[0-9]{1,9}"
        If .Test(str) Then
            Set realNum = .Execute(str)  'edited
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

realNum will be an Array with all the results specified with Regexp.
After getting realNum, with realNum(index) [start from 0] can get one occurence of any.
In your code with ndx you get only the (n+1)-th occurence.

Comment: I get an error when I run this version.  I am not sure if it's because if it's I've taken out the Cdbl out of the formula now as the decimal is not recognized.

Comment: @smak This function runs without error for me. The Execute function returns IMatchCollection2 of found text. Of course if you work later with the elements of it as a number you have to convert it to the required type.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want all decimal numbers, then you don't need the Optional parameter "Optional ndx As Integer = 1". The Function returns an Array Variable if it finds numbers, or an "Empty" Variable. The test for the result is shown in Sub Test()

```vb
' -------------GET ARRAY OF REAL NUMBERS IN A VARIANT (ARRAY)
Public Function realNum(str As String) As Variant
    Dim Collect As Object, v As Variant, c As Long  'Collect As IMatchCollection2
    Static rgx As Object

    ' with rgx as static, it only has to be created once; 
    ' beneficial when filling a long column with this UDF
    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .MultiLine = True
        ' don't use hard coding "." but Application.decimalSeparator for use anywhere
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,9}\" & Application.decimalSeparator & "[0-9]{1,9}"
        If .Test(str) Then
            Set Collect = .Execute(str)
            ' tranform and copy IMatchCollection2 items in a variable array, to return   
            If Collect.Count > 0 Then
               ReDim v(1 To Collect.Count)
               For c = 1 To Collect.Count
                  v(c) = CDbl(Collect(c - 1))
               Next
            End If

            realNum = v
       ' if you want can transpose here the array to be ready for
       ' use in cells. Just comment the above line: realNum = v
       ' and uncomment one of the lines below. If do this don't use TRANSPOSE in cells

            ' for use in column 
            'realNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(v)
            ' for use in row
            'realNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(v))
        End If
    End With
End Function


Sub Test()
   Dim v As Variant, c As Long

   v = realNum("60.75X30.75 Oak")
   ' the returned variant maybe is "Empty"
   ' or is an array (of double items) with base 1
   Debug.Print TypeName(v)
   ' check the type
   If TypeName(v) = "Empty" Then
      Debug.Print "Did not find any real numbers"
      Exit Sub
   End If
   Debug.Print LBound(v), UBound(v)
   For c = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
      Debug.Print (v(c))
   Next
End Sub
```

For usage in a cell we have to TRANSPOSE the array to see the values in column or have to TRANSPORT twice to see the values in row: (or modify what the function returns as i describe in comments inside the function)
(In my country the decimal separator is the comma , not the dot . )

[image]

In cell B1 write the formula. press Enter. You will see one value.
Select B1,B2,B3 press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER You will see all three values.

The equivalent if you want to get the values horizontally.

Comment: I keep getting an error with this part of the code "Dim Collect As IMatchCollection2".  I was using realNum as a function in the column next to list of styles, should I be selecting the whole column instead now?